# Question concerning the display (ribbon cable) port on the board

Tags: hardware, hdmi, display

I had an idea for a raspberry pi project, but i need some more info first.

I looked a bit but i didn't see anything about it, what connector type does the display (ribbon cable) connector use, and what protocol goes over it? I saw some micro-HDMI to ribbon cable adapters that would work good for me but i need to know which one would be appropriate to get and if it would even work. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The 'display (ribbon cable) port' is a DSI (Display Serial Interface) screen connection.

No you cannot simply use an hdmi to DSI ribbon cable adapter.

Quotes below from: https://www.seeedstudio.com/blog/2020/06/03/hdmi-micro-hdmi-vs-dsi-raspberry-pi-4-display-connectors-m/

**What is DSI?**

DSI stands for Display Serial Interface and it defines a high-speed serial interface between a host processor and a display module. It is often called as MIPI DSI (mobile industry processor interface display serial interface) because MIPI is the standard. However, DSI displays are purpose-built for specific devices, unlike HDMI. DSI interface is widely used in mobile phones, laptops, wearables, and various other devices.

**What is HDMI?**

HDMI stands for High Definition Multimedia Interface and it a connector and cable which has the ability to transmit both high-quality audio and video between devices. Also, the information sent over HDMI is uncompressed digital data, and this makes it possible for HDMI to transmit video signals at 4K resolution.